# How to load the SQL data into several ComboBox easily, am i doing the correctly or is there another way

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a Combobox to fill the data for City, State and PinCode
these combobox is dopdown list and the user will pick it.

and it loads once the form opens.

Here is the CODE:

```
            /// CODE TO BRING A DATA FROM SQL INTO THE FORM DROP LIST

            /// To fill the sates from States Table

            cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Nick-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AutoDB;Integrated Security=True");
            cmd= new SqlCommand("select * from TblState",cn);
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr;

            try
            {
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())

                {
                    SelectState.Items.Add(dr["State"].ToString());
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }

            //To fill the Cities from City Table

            cn1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Nick-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AutoDB;Integrated Security=True");
            cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TblCity", cn);
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader ds;

            try
            {
                ds = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                while (ds.Read())
                {
                    SelectCity.Items.Add(ds["City"].ToString());
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                cn1.Close();
            }

            // To fill the Data in the Pincode from the City Table
            cn2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Nick-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AutoDB;Integrated Security=True");
            cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT (Pincode) FROM TblCity ", cn2);
            cn2.Open();
            SqlDataReader dm;

            try
            {
                dm = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                while (dm.Read())
                {
                    SelectPinCode.Items.Add(dm["Pincode"].ToString());
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                cn2.Close();
            }
```

its kinda Big, i am doing the same steps for all the combo-box, but is there a way i can merge it in a simple way.

Comment: What version of .NET are you on?

Comment: I am using the visual basic 2010 ultimate edition and i guss its 4.0 or can u tell me how to find it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stick-to-the-basics approach - refactor your code into a single method.

```
static IEnumerable<string> Load(string tableName, string columnName)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Nick-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AutoDB;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, cn))
            {
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        result.Add(reader[columnName].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Crude assumptions made:

1. Only querying 1 table, 1 column.
2. Not checking for nulls on the `IDataReader`.

Comment: I think it is good way around, but it can be better by sending whole query string as parameter. Because '"SELECT * FROM " + tableName' kind of code is open to SQL Injection and selecting everything using '*' won't be necessery then. 
One more thing: Dominic Deepan.d, in case you don't know, you will set data source of combobox to the result of this method.

Comment: T.q boss, its really helpful, i will use it :D

Answer (score 0):

```
cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Nick-PC\SQLEXPRESS;InitialCatalog=AutoDB;Integrated  Security=True");
cmd= new SqlCommand("select * from TblState",cn);
cn.Open();
SqlDataReader dr;
try
{
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        SelectState.Items.Add(dr["State"].ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    cn.Close();
}
//To fill the Cities from City Table
// To fill the Data in the Pincode from the City Table
cn2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Nick-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AutoDB;Integrated Security=True");
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TblCity ", cn2);
cn2.Open();
SqlDataReader dm;
try
{
    dm = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    while (dm.Read())
    {
        SelectPinCode.Items.Add(dm["Pincode"].ToString());
        //since you are using only one City table to get PinCode and City name this would be better.
        SelectCity.Items.Add(ds["City"].ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    cn2.Close();
}
```

Comment: Yep, i had the pincode and city in same table, but i had to remove it.

because in my place in each city there are hundreds of pincodes.
and picodes refer to a particular location in a city.

but thanks for the code... it was really helpful :)